# pl/sql block, weird errors with simple script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm writing very simple block code in pl/sql:

```
DECLARE
  dateof21 DATE;
  dzien number;
  dzien_tyg number;
BEGIN

dateof21:= '2001-01-01';

WHILE dateof21 != '2101-01-01' LOOP

 SELECT EXTRACT(day from date dateof21) INTO dzien from dual;

 select to_char(date dateof21,'D') INTO dzien_tyg from dual;

if ((dzien=13) AND (dzien_tyg=5)) THEN

  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(dateof21));

end if;

  dateof21:= dateof21+1;

END LOOP;

END;
```

but i'm getting very annoying errors:

> ORA-06550: linia 8, kolumna 26:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00936: brak wyrażenia
>   ORA-06550: linia 8, kolumna 2:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: linia 9, kolumna 17:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00936: brak wyrażenia
>   ORA-06550: linia 9, kolumna 2:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

I really tried to find whats wrong, but everything seems just fine. Can anybody help? it should write on output all fridays which are 13th day of month btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong in your code:

First: you should use proper date literals. I prefer ANSI literals, like `DATE '2001-01-01'` but you can also use the `to_date()`function: `to_date('2001-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Second: `to_char()` returns a varchar value, not a number. So you can't assign the result of that to a number variable, you need to use `to_number(to_char(dateof21,'D'))`.

You also don't need to use `select ... into` to call a function.

And finally: the `extract()` method does not require the use of a `date` prefix: `EXTRACT(day from dateof21)`

Putting that all together, gives us:

```
DECLARE
  dateof21 DATE;
  dzien number;
  dzien_tyg number;
BEGIN
  dateof21 := date '2001-01-01';
  -- alternatively: dateof21 := to_date('2001-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');

  WHILE dateof21 <> DATE '2101-01-01' 
  LOOP
    dzien := EXTRACT(day from dateof21);
    dzien_tyg := to_number(to_char(dateof21,'D'));

    if ((dzien=13) AND (dzien_tyg=5)) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(to_char(dateof21, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
    end if;

    dateof21 := dateof21+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

Note that the return value of `to_char(dateof21,'D')` depends on your NLS settings. You can't rely on it to *always* return `5` for a friday in all configurations (e.g. on my computer it returns `6`).

Comment: Thank you so much ;p I've just started with PL/SQL so i'm doing stupid mistakes and don`t know much yet ;P